# How do you time jump animation with uneven landing surface?

Tags: animation, jumping

Say my player jumps off from a certain point on a 2D surface. Say my surface is uneven, and has varying y positions along the level, how would I then be able to time my jump animation accordingly?
(The issue being is that the animation might get cut off half way through, or vice versa - the animation would be already finished while the player is still jumping/landing)

Comment: Can you give us a bit more detail about exactly what kind of animation/transition you're trying to implement, and how it relates to the height of the surface? There are a number of possibilities, and we want to make sure you get advice that's relevant to the approach you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, when working on jumping mechanics, instead of relying on the duration of the animation, the motion is split in 3 (sometimes even more, but most of the times 3 is enough) animations:

- Jump from the ground animation
- in air /falling animation
- landing animation

In Unity, you could merge these three animations inside a [blendtree](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-BlendTree.html) while changing its state (jumping/in air/landing) based on a boolean parameter which is usually called `isGrounded`.

`IsGrounded`, as the name implies, checks if the player is grounded. To set this variable properly, there are two main ways:

- you could either shoot a Raycast from the character origin to the ground(it has to be parallel to the global y axis);
- or a sphere Cast(the same a raycast, but it's using a sphere mesh, to get a bit more precision).

You can see the two different approaches described in more detail [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/151636/how-to-solve-the-ground-check-problem/151637#151637)

Via the player script, you can just set `isGrounded`'s value inside with:

```
Animator anim;
bool value;

void Start()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

void Update()
{
    // set 'value' to true if the player is grounded, set it to false if it's not
    //then set the isGrounded bool inside the animator
    anim.SetBool("isGrounded",value);
}
```